# React-router API - defining routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use the react-redux-firebase app as a base for my app.

I'm trying to add static pages to the footer links (no state) and then render them as the app expects.

I haven't seen this approach to setting up a route index.js before.

The generator creates this index file (to which I have tried to add the About route):

```
import CoreLayout from '../layouts/CoreLayout'
import Home from './Home'
import LoginRoute from './Login'
import SignupRoute from './Signup'
import ProjectsRoute from './Projects'
import AccountRoute from './Account'
import NotFoundRoute from './NotFound'
import AboutPage from "./About"


/*  Note: Instead of using JSX, we recommend using react-router
    PlainRoute objects to build route definitions.   */

export const createRoutes = store => ({
  path: '/',
  component: CoreLayout,
  indexRoute: Home,
  childRoutes: [
    AccountRoute(store),
    LoginRoute(store),
    SignupRoute(store),
    ProjectsRoute(store),
    AboutPage,
    // AsyncRoute(store) // async routes setup by passing store
    // SyncRoute, // sync routes just need route object by itself
    /* Place all Routes above here so NotFoundRoute can act as a 404 page */
    NotFoundRoute(store)
  ]
})

/*  Note: childRoutes can be chunked or otherwise loaded programmatically
    using getChildRoutes with the following signature:

    getChildRoutes (location, cb) {
      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        cb(null, [
          // Remove imports!
          require('./Counter').default(store)
        ])
      })
    }

    However, this is not necessary for code-splitting! It simply provides
    an API for async route definitions. Your code splitting should occur
    inside the route `getComponent` function, since it is only invoked
    when the route exists and matches.
*/

export default createRoutes
```

This app layout is that all the views seem to be setup under the routes folder. Following that approach, I made an AboutPage folder within src/routes/About/components. That folder has a AboutPage folder with a js page and in index, as well as separate index.js file (similar to the HomePage component provided with the generated app). The nested index has:

```
import AboutPage from './AboutPage'

export default AboutPage
```

The src/routes/About/index.js

```
import AboutPage from './components/AboutPage/index.js'

// Sync route definition
export default {
  component: AboutPage
}
```

I don't get any errors when I save this, but when I start the server and click the link, I just get a 404 error.

How do I add routes to this app?

I have tried a million different variations on the import statement in the routes/index.js - many of which produce no error but do not actually render the page.

The full setup is src/routes/About/components/AboutPage/AboutPage.js

```
class About extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  }
  render() {
    const { classes, ...rest } = this.props;
    const imageClasses = classNames(
      classes.imgCard,
      classes.imgFluid
    );
    const navImageClasses = classNames(classes.imgRounded, classes.imgGallery);
    return (
      <div>
        -- intentionally deleted copy --
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(profilePageStyle)(About);
```

Then, src/routes/components/AboutPage/index.js:

```
import AboutPage from './AboutPage'

export default AboutPage
```

Then src/routes/About/index.js

```
import AboutPage from './components/AboutPage/index.js'

// Sync route definition
export default {
  component: AboutPage
}
```

Then routes/index.js - shown as above.

I have read this several times- I can't make sense of it. If the child doesn't have state, then I don't see why a store would be relevant.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#plainroute

Comment: Just glancing at the example you draw from, in the routes with no store connection (e.g. [`SignUp`](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/master/examples/complete/material/src/routes/Signup/index.js)) there's an additional export `path` in the file. You may want to include that to point to `/about`.

Comment: @shinglesmingles - are you referring to the enhancer?

Comment: No, referencing src/routes/About/index.js

Comment: @shinglesmingles - I don't understand what you mean. The signup form export path includes a store enhancer in the index file for that component. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry I think I referenced the wrong example (didn't really get specifics on the generator you were using). Maybe it's best to follow the template from the [NotFound](https://github.com/prescottprue/generator-react-firebase/blob/master/examples/react-firebase-redux/src/routes/NotFound/index.js) route instead, replacing `path: '*'` with `path: '/about'`

Comment: @shinglesmingles - that doesn't make any sense. The not found example has it's own const definition that is bundled separately. Thanks for trying to help but I don't think this is the solution.